# Incomplete xml files in Android studio after installation

Tags: android-studio

When i install Android studio i just clicked on build, some errors shows up in xml files like ic_launcher_foreground, ic_launcher, ic_launcher_round.
Code in these files haven't been already completed. I try to reinstall but don't work.
I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to delete **ic_launcher_round v26** with cleaning and building this what happens.

FYI
please do not post images here, rather explain your question properly.
[Please do not post images of code/errors when asked question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)